# What happens to Element cards spent when acquiring a new Element card?

Tags: the-big-book-of-madness

In the co-op game *[The Big Book of Madness](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/171233/big-book-madness)*, the rules say the following about when you acquire a new *Element* card:

> As long as one is available, you can acquire 1 Element card of value
>   2 or 3 from the middle of the table. You must spend Elements of the
>   same type as the Element card you wish to acquire. [...] When you acquire an Element card, place it in your discard.

So you spend several *Element* cards to acquire a new *Element* card of the same combined value. The new card goes in your discard.

Do you destroy the spent *Element* cards or do they go in your discard as well?

Comment: why would they be destroyed? Every other time you use an element card it is placed in your discard.

Comment: That's what I thought but destroying small element cards would also increase the odds of getting higher cards from your deck. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You are correct that destroying lesser value cards would make it easier to get higher value, and thus better, cards from your deck. That is the reason why they are harder to destroy as you are already making the deck better by adding the cards and removing the old cards would make it even better.

Comment: So the way to improve your deck would be to use combustion on the 1 element cards to destroy them. Though it would make your deck turnover quicker and increase the pace of madness kicking in.

Comment: Yes, using that spell and others that destroy cards is the only way remove cards to improve your deck.

Answer (score 1):

You place the cards used in the discard pile as stated in the action phase section of the [rules](http://www.iellogames.com/downloads/BigBook_EN_Rules.pdf).

> During the Action phase, you may use your Element and
>   Spell cards to try to vanquish the Monster and keep it in the
>   Grimoire. Five actions are possible:
>   • Activate a Spell
>   • Learn a new Spell
>   • Acquire an Element card
>   • Destroy a Curse
>   • Cure one of your Madness cards
>   You may take as many actions as you wish, in any order, as many
>   times as you like, as long as you have the Element cards to pay for
>   them. Each action costs a number of Elements, which you must pay
>   by discarding Element cards from your hand or from the support
>   pool or a combination of both.
>   Whenever you pay an Activation Cost, you must discard enough
>   Element cards to produce at least as many Elements as required
>   for the action. Excess Elements spent on an Action are lost. They
>   cannot be used for another Action.
>   A single Element card cannot be used for multiple Actions.